# Javascript push array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I create the data array from my second api call result into the format I want?
I have a code like this

```
var github = require('octonode');
var client = github.client();
var userName = "octocat";
var repoName = "";
var branchName = "";
var data = [];
var branches = [];

client.get('/users/'+userName+'/repos', {}, function (err, status, body, headers) {
  body.forEach(function(obj) {
    repoName = obj.name;
    //==============================
      client.get('repos/'+userName+'/'+repoName+'/branches', {}, function (errx, statusx, bodyChild, headersx) {
      bodyChild.forEach(function(objChild) {
        branchName = objChild.name;
          });
      });
    });
});
```

I have received `repoName` and `branchName` data as well.

I want my data format like

[image]

How to use

```
data.push({
   name: repoName,
   branches: 'branchName loooping here for every repoName'
});
```

so `branches` repetition data can be contained in my branches tag

Thank you

Comment: You need to push into the inner array.

Comment: hi @SLaks can you give me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do something like this:

```
var data = [];

client.get('/users/'+userName+'/repos', {}, function (err, status, body, headers) {
  body.forEach(function(obj) {
    repoName = obj.name;
    client.get('repos/'+userName+'/'+repoName+'/branches', {}, function (errx, statusx, bodyChild, headersx) {
        let elem = {"name": repoName, "branches": []}; //create json object for each repo 
        bodyChild.forEach(function(objChild) {
          elem.branches.push(objChild.name); //push all branchs to that elem
        });
        data.push(elem); // add the elem to the data array
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @David, when I try your code the result is empty when I check `console.log(data);`

Comment: My mistake...sorry
Thanks @David

Answer (score 0):

So in this case `data` is an object, that has a property `name` which is string, and another property `branches` which is array. If you want to push data to the property `branches` you can just call the `push()` function on it.

Please check the example below:

```js
    let data = {
        name: "repoName",
        branches: [
            {
                name: "foo"
            }
        ]
    }

    data.branches.push(
        {
            name: "bar"
        }
    );

    console.log(data);
```